# Local notification not working with iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, ios9, uilocalnotification

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have the following code:

```
//Create date
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let now = NSDate()

let dateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: now)

dateComponents.minute += 2 //add 2 minutes to current time for debug

let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)

//Create notification
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Your task is now available"
notification.alertAction = "open"
notification.fireDate = date
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["id": NSUUID().UUIDString]
notification.category = "Notification"
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

When I place a breakpoint in application: didReceiveLocalNotification in app delegate, it never gets called.

Comment: When Local Notification turned on, close the app, then check.

Comment: How do you turn on notifications? There's no Notifications setting in the Setting app of the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question. In AppDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I had to register notifications like so:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Comment: As of iOS 10, registerUserNotificationSettings is deprecated. Instead you can use: requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)