How can I send an iOS local push to a specific date and schedule it weekday for a particular time?
I want to add and send an iOS local push notification to a specific date and want to schedule it by weekday for a specific time (hour, minute). I wanted to send this reminder weekday-wise but want to remove today's if use already took/achieved his today's goal. I've tried with the code below but failed to send it, please check the code below.
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

public extension Date {
    func noon(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
    func day(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.day, from: self)
    }
    func weekday(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.weekday, from: self)
    }
    func hour(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.hour, from: self)
    }
    func minute(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.minute, from: self)
    }
    func second(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.second, from: self)
    }
    func adding(_ component: Calendar.Component, value: Int, using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: self)!
    }
    func monthSymbol(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> String {
        calendar.monthSymbols[calendar.component(.month, from: self)-1]
    }
    func addDay(n: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: n, to: self)!
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    private let categoryID = "Category"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let actionShowSomething = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ShowSomething", title: "Show Something", options: [])
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryID, actions: [actionShowSomething], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    }
    
    @IBAction func addNotification(_ sender: Any) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        // Request Notification Settings
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (notificationSettings) in
            switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined:
                self.requestAuthorization(completionHandler: { (success) in
                    guard success else { return }
                    self.scheduleLocalNotification()
                })
            case .authorized:
                self.scheduleLocalNotification()
            case .denied:
                print("Application Not Allowed to Display Notifications")
            case .provisional:
                break
            case .ephemeral:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func requestAuthorization(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> ()) {
        // Request Authorization
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (success, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request Authorization Failed (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
            }
            completionHandler(success)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - ScheduleLocalNotification
    private func scheduleLocalNotification() {
        let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notificationContent.title = "Title"
        notificationContent.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        notificationContent.body = "Body"
        notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = categoryID
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        dateComponents.calendar = calendar
        let date = Date()
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        dateComponents.weekday = 2 + 7  // Monday = 2
        dateComponents.second = second + 30
        
        let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "cocoacasts_local_notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
    }
}


Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35999230/833395 you might missed something, for testing just put dateComponents.seconds = 5, so every 5 seconds local notification will trigger

But I want to skip today and want to reschedule it for next weekday, is it possible?

you can schedule the date by miniusing some seconds from current date like ?

@AMIT – in my answer below, I assumed that when you said “weekday-wise”, that you meant it in the everyday use of the term (e.g., Mon-Fri in common Gregorian calendars). Is that correct? Or did you want the notification to fire every day, both “weekdays” and “weekends”? (The Calendar API’s use of the term weekday is confusing, IMHO, actually meaning “day of the week”, including weekends.)

I want to send it every Sunday at 10:30 am only. But if the user takes any reading (or skips today's notification) and skips upcoming notification, then it will show next Sunday.  @Rob

I gather that you intend to add a recurring user notification (say, every Sunday at 10:30 a.m.), but you want the ability to optionally skip the first one.
A single, repeating, user notification is incapable of that: It will fire on every match of the date components, including the first one you may have wanted to skip.
In this case, I would suggest scheduling a series of individual, non-repeating notifications. But, because there is a limit as to how many non-repeating notifications you can schedule (64 the last time I checked), I might fallback to a single repeating notification if you do not need to skip the first one:
nonisolated func schedule(
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    body: String,
    skipFirst: Bool = false,
    weekday: Int,
    hour: Int,
    minute: Int
) async throws {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    if skipFirst {
        try await scheduleMultipleIndividualSkippingFirst(
            title: title,
            subtitle: subtitle,
            body: body,
            weekday: weekday,
            hour: hour,
            minute: minute
        )
    } else {
        try await scheduleSingleRepeating(
            title: title,
            subtitle: subtitle,
            body: body,
            weekday: weekday,
            hour: hour,
            minute: minute
        )
    }
}

Where you have two renditions, one that schedules a single repeating user notification, and another that schedules a series of non-repeating user notifications, one for each of the future dates:
private nonisolated func scheduleSingleRepeating(
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    body: String,
    weekday: Int,
    hour: Int,
    minute: Int
) async throws {
    let components = DateComponents(hour: hour, minute: minute, weekday: weekday)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)

    let request = notificationRequest(
        identifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".repeating",
        title: title,
        subtitle: subtitle,
        body: body,
        trigger: trigger
    )

    try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}

private nonisolated func scheduleMultipleIndividualSkippingFirst(
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    body: String,
    weekday: Int,
    hour: Int,
    minute: Int
) async throws {
    let components = DateComponents(hour: hour, minute: minute, weekday: weekday)

    // skip the first one

    var date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: .now, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)

    // but now schedule a year worth of individual user notifications
    for i in 0 ..< 52 {
        date = date.flatMap { Calendar.current.nextDate(after: $0, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime) }
        guard let date else { return }

        let triggerComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerComponents, repeats: false)

        let request = notificationRequest(
            identifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".individual\(i)",
            title: title,
            subtitle: subtitle,
            body: body,
            trigger: trigger
        )

        try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
}

private nonisolated func notificationRequest(
    identifier: String,
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    body: String,
    trigger: UNNotificationTrigger
) -> UNNotificationRequest {
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = title
    notificationContent.subtitle = subtitle
    notificationContent.body = body

    return UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
}

Admittedly this process of scheduling a series of individual user notifications is not ideal, as you are limited to 64 of them, but then, again, if the user never opens your app for over a year, it may be a moot point.

In my original answer, below, I assumed you were just trying to add user notifications for every non-weekend day of the week. I now gather that this was not your intent, but I will keep it here for posterity’s sake.

The main issue is that dateComponents.weekday = 2 + 7 pattern will not work. You want a weekday value that is in the range of 1..<8. Setting it to 9, as you have in your code snippet, is unlikely to work.
If you really want the next weekday (i.e., excluding weekends) at the appointed hour and minute, the simple UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching:repeats:) approach will not work. You want to set the date components to match one of the values in 1..<8. So, there are two possible approaches:

You might schedule five repeating notifications, one for each non-weekend day of the week (e.g., Mon-Fri in common western calendars):
for weekday in Calendar.current.weekdaysExcludingWeekends() {
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = "Title"
    notificationContent.subtitle = "Subtitle"
    notificationContent.body = "Body"

    let components = DateComponents(hour: datePicker.date.hour(), minute: datePicker.date.minute(), weekday: weekday)
    print(weekday, components.hour!, components.minute!)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "cocoacasts_local_notification.\(weekday)", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)

    try await notificationCenter.add(request)
}

Where:
extension Calendar {
    func weekdaysExcludingWeekends() -> [Int] {
        let now: Date = .now
        let daysOfWeek = Calendar.current.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: now) ?? 1..<8
        return daysOfWeek.filter { weekday in
            let date = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .weekday, value: weekday, of: now)!
            return !Calendar.current.isDateInWeekend(date)
        }
    }
}


You could alternatively schedule non-repeating notifications, and calculate a series of individual non-weekend Date for the given hour and minute:
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.nextWeekday(after: date, hour: 14, minute: 0)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: date)
let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)

Where:
extension Calendar {
    func nextWeekday(after startDate: Date = .now, hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Date {
        var date = startDate

        let components = DateComponents(calendar: self, hour: hour, minute: minute)

        repeat {
            date = nextDate(after: date, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
        } while isDateInWeekend(date)

        return date
    }
}

But that only creates one notification. You would have to repeat this for all individual future notifications that you want. (And there are a limited number of notification you can set, so if you really want repeating notifications, you’d probably want to pursue the first option, above.)



There are other issues here:

Probably unrelated, but you set the delegate for the UNUserNotificationCenter in the view controller.
The documentation is clear that this must do this in the app delegate. (I know that Cocoacasts tutorial does it in the view controller, but you really should do it in the app delegate.)

To guarantee that your app responds to all actionable notifications, you must set the value of this property before your app finishes launching. For an iOS app, this means updating this property in the application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method of the app delegate. Notifications that cause your app to be launched or delivered shortly after these methods finish executing.

So, either have the app delegate conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, or, better, have it instantiate some other, service object to conform to this protocol. But the setting of the notification center delegate must happen in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or willFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

You are setting the categoryIdentifier for the UNMutableNotificationContent.
For the vast majority of notifications, we would not do that. You only do that if you really have your UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate implement userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) (or its async brethren, userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:))
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case "ShowSomething":
            await doSomethingSpectacular()
        default:
            print("unknown category")
        }
    }
}

(As an aside, just like you put categoryID in a constant, I would tend to do the same with the action identifiers, avoiding littering my codebase with string literals, but I wanted to keep it simple.)
Anyway, again, that is a less common use-case. Generally we would not set categoryIdentifier for the notification content at all. But that is up to you. But if you do, you must support it in the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.
Now, if (a) you need this behavior; and (b) you implemented one of the userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) methods in your delegate, then forgive this observation. But that implementation was not included in the question, and I just wanted to note that sometimes if one neglects to implement a required delegate method, it can interfere with the correct behavior.


